# Note4 freezes and crashes except when running aLogrec

Tags: updates, crashes, logging, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-note-4

My Note4 started locking up and crashing after the last OS update a week or so ago (to 6.0.1). I ended up having to do a factory reset twice. The first time I tried to restore from Google's backup and had the same problems.

I also installed aLogrec and found that the problems seemed less frequent.
Unfortunately i never managed to get at the logs before the reset.
After the last reinstall I just kept aLogrec running and had no problem for about 2 days. Today I turned off  aLogrec and had 2 lock ups within several hours.

The lockup are so severe that I need to remove the battery. Holding down the power button for over a minute does not help.

What would explain this behaviour?